# Instantly open Web Inspector for iOS WebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm developing an iOS app with WebView. 
I need to debug is so that's what I do:

1. Open WebView on iOS
2. Go to desktop Safari -> Develop -> iPhone ->

The problem is some script takes place the moment WebView opens. So when I open Web Inspector all I see is just a blank page. 
Is there any way to pause page processing before Web Inspector is opened?

Answer (score 0):

For such cases, I would place a UIButton somewhere in the layout, and request the url, only when the button is pressed. That is you will have a WKWebView initiated and available in your screen and you only navigate to the url path on the tap event of the UIButton.

This is just for debugging purposes.